# 2016 Moderator Election. Meh

Tags: discussion

By fiat or tradition or something, all candidates for moderator are self-nominated. What could possibly go wrong?

Well, first of all, there's the rampant [Dunning Kruger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect) syndrome, in which the skills of the sufferers are inversely proportional to their confidence in their illusory skill. This explains the survey results that show that 80% of people surveyed on a topic think they're in the top 20% of experts in that topic.

Let me hasten to add that this is a societal issue (at  least in the US), and not one particular to ELU. And while I'm hastening to add things, let me also say that this isn't directed to anyone in particular in this year's list of hopefuls and that I include myself as possibly infected.

The second problem is that those striving to attain authority over others thereby offer prima facie evidence that they shouldn't be allowed anywhere near that authority. This applies to the police, the military, the political apparat, and moderators of online forums. Perhaps all will turn out for the best, but by my count more than half the self-nominees are card-carrying members of the CPVPV, and there's at least one I once regarded as a stalker.

There are other ways of selecting moderators, but I don't know of better ways given that the gentle con of the StackExchange business plan is based on convincing people to exchange their time, effort, and expertise for the nugatory.

Will the election results be streamed live this year? I, for one, can't wait to hear the stirring words "May I have the envelope, please."

~~~~~~~~

"... unclear what you're asking. Please edit your question." OK, I don't mind if I do. First, I call nonsense. Not least because this isn't *Jeopardy*. Many discussion topics do not appear as questions, especially when it comes to discussing the mechanics of keeping out the riff-raff. We've heard calls for forcing newcomers watch a [video](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8215/are-low-quality-questions-and-answers-here-to-stay), requiring them to [register](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8191/can-we-require-a-new-user-to-register-before-posting), and making them post bond before they can post questions.

(OK, I made that last one up.)

But all of a sudden, when it comes to a discussion of the mechanics of moderator selection, things become so murky the "question" needs to be put on hold. At least in the opinion of one moderator, one candidate for moderator, and one other who seems eminently qualified for the position.

This is exactly the kind of behavior I'm talking about.

So is it clear yet?

Now maybe this is pointless to discuss because the procedure is set in stone system wide. And maybe it's fair to criticize me for not proposing alternatives. (Sorry, I don't have any. I've dealt with one other site in which the moderators groom high-rep users for an invitation to join their circle. I didn't think that worked any better.) But these are different considerations.

But thanks for making my point for me. Well played!

Comment: Care to explain what the CPVPV is?

Comment: This is inflammatory. There is no need for stirring the pot when there's enough substantive issues and substantive people to discuss them.

Comment: Rather than spending your time, effort, and expertise complaining about the candidates, why not instead spend it on encouraging someone you like to nominate himself?

Comment: @Mitch *enough ... substantive people* What's that supposed to mean? That I'm not a substantive person? If so, that would be inflammatory enough to hurt my feelings.  If I had any. I understand that one man's substantive issue is another man's piffle. That's what another man's downvotes are for. In spite of my style, I consider this a serious problem. If you closevoted because you disagree, that's contemptible. If you didn't closevote, never mind.

Comment: @zaq Questions on meta don't necessarily have to ask anything. I don't know how to state my thesis any more clearly. You have valid criticism that I haven't proposed any solutions to the downside of self-nomination. I'm sorry about that, but I don't have any. That doesn't mean they don't exist.

Comment: @DanBron To be fair, it took little time, less effort, and no expertise. Alas, there is no one like me, and if there were, he or she wouldn't self-nominate for the auto-disqualification reason given in my post.

Comment: The rule requiring [self-nomination](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75382/how-can-you-nominate-someone-other-than-yourself-for-being-a-moderator/75429#75429) is indeed by fiat and network-wide, so if you want to challenge it, I think you'd have to take it up with Stack Exchange. Complaining about the mechanics of SE elections on ELU Meta seems about as productive as complaining here about the mechanics of downvotes.

Comment: @sumelic Not productive? That's your problem with the post? That's adorable. Really. But I suppose it's better than inflammatory.

Comment: There is a chat room available for discussion of the merits and flaws of the candidates: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43655/2016-english-language-moderator-election

Comment: I'm not sure I have a problem with this post. As a candidate, I'd prefer if you gave specific criticisms rather than vague generalities and insinuations, but it's up to you how you want to participate in discussions about the election. I'm just trying to suggest some alternative ways you could pursue your goals.

Comment: @sumelic Well, that's a fair cop. I find the mechanics of chat annoying, and my complaint has less to do with individual candidates than with the process that caters to a general propensity that I suspect I'm inclined to as much as anyone. And notice that it's *not* up to me how I participate in discussions about the election. Shall we start the countdown clock on the remaining lifetime of this thread?  Or am I being too harsh?

Comment: Make that three, not four. My mistake.

Comment: Good point; it actually isn't entirely up to you. As with all posts on Stack Exchange, this is subject to moderation by community members and diamond moderators. I didn't meant to imply that their actions were illegitimate with my previous comment; I was mainly indicating my own opinion about this post. As one of the candidates in this election, I thought it was better for me to not take any moderatorial actions on this post, and I didn't see any pressing reason for it to be closed. That said, I also don't see any reason for it to be reopened.

Comment: Not all Meta posts have to be questions, but I think this one is a particularly bad fit for the Q-&-sorted-A format. Most Meta posts at least present a topic for discussion, where people can upvote the "answers" that correspond best to their viewpoints or that propose a course of action they agree with. The first topic you bring up, self-nomination, is a network-wide policy not set by this community (so as I said earlier, community input here is unlikely to do anything) and only relevant to the nomination portion of the election, which is almost over and done with.

Comment: The second topic you bring up, the perceived unsuitability of all the moderator candidates (and insinuations of wrongdoing on the part of an unspecified subset of them), is very broad and better discussed in the chat room.

Comment: @sumelic *Good point* Yes, it is, and one that I'm afraid you missed. Although there are always limits, people (including me) are pretty much entirely free to participate in such discussions on other topics. *Bad fit* I take your point; that's what downvoting is for. *Better discussed in the chat room* I take that point too, and when they make chat convenient, I'll use it.

Comment: @sumelic *Better for me to not take* That commends you. No *reason for it to be closed* I guess we'll see how long that forbearance lasts if you win the election.

Comment: @deadrat I'm no member of any committee, and I'm sure you've seen all the other supposed members of the CPVPV disagree with me vehemently before.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to discuss here. Is it the process of nomination, philosophy, the psychology of those who want to lead, or something else? I hear that you have negative feelings--you seem bitter, but I may misunderstand your intent--and I would like to have a better understanding of what you are trying to express so that I can at least attempt to address your expectations.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox Yes, yes, yes, and perhaps. I don't have feelings, at least not in cyberspace. There are things that have and do make me bitter, but trust me, none of them occurs online. We have no access to anyone's intent here, so it's best to stick with the words. I've expressed my opinions and made my observations as clearly as I can. Anything more would be repetition. I appreciate your concern. My style requires that I state that the previous sentence is not snark.

Comment: @curiousdannii Do you understand that it's a figure of speech? I can't tell whether you do or not.

Comment: @deadrat I think you're trying to be funny and failing hard. You disagree with the official guidelines and standards of this community and are trying to pin it on a small group rather than recognising that they were determined through the consensus of the whole community, and can be readily changed again through that consensus process.

Comment: @deadrat Well sorry for misjudging you. Most people don't invent very cute acronyms when they're being deadly serious.

Comment: [I've learnt something new.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Committee_for_the_Promotion_of_Virtue_and_the_Prevention_of_Vice) Which just makes @deadrat's use of it even more offensive. There is no comparison between the well-meaning users of this site trying to uphold the consensus site standards and Islamic religious police enforcing Sharia law. You're right that it's not a joke.

Comment: Although the Saudi CPVPV may be the direct referent for deadrat's term, a very similar impulse exists in UK and US history, with the [Society for the Suppression of Vice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Society_for_the_Suppression_of_Vice) and the [New York Society for the Suppression of Vice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_Society_for_the_Suppression_of_Vice), to name two such moral crusaders. (I suppose that the Saudi CPVPV might object to being characterized as crusaders—but they certainly align with their Christian counterparts on the need to fumigate society for its own good.)

Comment: I don't know if you consider me a member of your fictitious society of prudes—I assume not since I am not that active here anymore—but be that as it may, I honestly have no idea what you are trying to say here. If you want to discuss the election process, please edit your post and clarify what your issues are. As far as I can tell, your first two sentences are the only ones that are actually relevant to ELU. I have read the question twice now and still have no idea what you actually want to discuss.

Comment: @terdon You get that I don't think there's an actual "society", right? I'm talking metaphorically about a group of people I consider over-zealous. They're certainly not fictitious, and their problem isn't prudery. I can't say that I've noticed you amongst them. Read JEL's answer below, and maybe a third reading of the OP will reveal to you that I'm talking about the deleterious effect of people nominating themselves for a position of authority.

Comment: @deadrat Hello, friend. 1. It really is odd to nominate myself. But unless you suggest a better method, what good does this post do? 2. I've been reading your posts about "CPVPV", and I don't know how that term fits me or others who actively participate in site maintenance. I'd consider it offensive, if that was directed at me.

Comment: @NVZ 1. So if I find a problem but I, myself can't think of a solution, then I should just remain quiet. Is that your general advice or just for this issue?

Comment: @NVZ 2. Is *site maintenance* a euphemism? Or are you talking about flagging spam and working the queues?

Comment: @deadrat 1. As a civil engineer, I always suggest ideas where I see a problem, and ask my peers for advice. That's how we build great structures, not by ranting (I kinda think yours is a rant). General advice, yes.

Comment: @NVZ Well, I'm neither as civil nor as clever as you are, then. Sometimes I have no solutions. And if you're talking about just the OP, then you have a very low threshold for rant. Are you sure you don't just mean it was something you didn't like?

Comment: @deadrat 2. "*Site maintenance* encompasses all the activities needed to guarantee the operational integrity of a site". As a regular user, I use the tools that I have, and I invest my time and effort to keep ELU a first-class Q&A site for us all. I wouldn't have come to ELU if it was just like any other forum.

Comment: @deadrat You may think I'm opposing you, I'm not. I really like you as a person. Plus, I agreed that "self-nomination is odd". But, I'm kind of opposed to the tone of the OP, it is a long-winded complaint. I sincerely want to help you with whatever this is about, but you suggest no option to do that.

Comment: @NVZ Why do people insist on telling me what I think or feel? I don't think you're "opposing" me; I think you're telling how you received something I wrote. And you like me as a person? Thanks, I guess, but what do you even know about me? Trust me, I'm even more unpleasant in person than I am in cyberspace. You want to help? Then why not stop reading tone into text and respond to the words? And long winded? The OP is about 260 words. I just wrote a longer answer about the word *comorbid*. Or was that too long as well?

Comment: I completely agree with you that at least half of the self-nominees are not qualified. But this is not a problem at all *as long as (a) there are at least 2 who are fit to do the job; and (b) the community will actually vote for those who are fit to do the job*. Unqualified applicants are everywhere, including ordinary jobs, politics, etc. It is just how the system works.

Comment: Whoa, there, @Matsmath. You're agreeing with something I haven't claimed. My problem isn't with this crop of nominees, and I'm not making a blanket indictment of the current moderatorship. I think self-nomination has a tendency to select hall monitors (perhaps in BrE, this would be called head boyism). And if the "system" doesn't work, perhaps the system ought to be changed.

Comment: Let me reconsider my comment then: I have the view that in any kind of elections/job applications/etc. at least half of the self-promoted candidates/applicants are absolutely not qualified. I also have the view, that having given a superficial look to the candidates' profile, this general phenomenon very likely to apply to the current election. As an unrelated note, I also happen to have the view that it is better to appoint candidates who have inner motivation to do this job (that is, they nominate themselves to be a moderator) than asking someone who might be not interested at all...

Comment: @Matsmath It's a certainty, isn't it? If at least half of the 11 nominees are unqualified, that means 6 are unqualified. Since 10 will go to the election, the best that can happen is that 5 unqualified nominees will stand for election. I take your point that self-nomination is more likely to get candidates with the motivation, but people solicit members to self-nominate, and these folks seem to have no trouble turning down the requests.

Comment: You know, after some reflection I've come to the realization that there is another motivation behind people offering to be moderators. It's not a question of power, or control, but one dictated by a need to feel useful. There are people who want to feel useful in lives, and feel the desire to make a difference. I don't think everyone who self-nominates him or herself is on some sort of ego or power trip, but they may be in self-denial about their abilities and personality qualities. As for self-nominating, it makes sense because the role is a voluntary one, you volunteer to lend your time.

Answer (score 14):

To answer your first question, there are problems with self-nomination, as you yourself have conveniently summarized.

I'm sure you will forgive me if I take umbrage to your claim that anyone who would self-nominate is unqualified for the post. You will recall that *all eight* of the current moderation team self-nominated for the position, including nohat (who was previously appointed as pro tem) and waiwai (who was appointed when Kosmonaut left). I think the moderation team is doing a good job. I haven't heard anything to the contrary recently.

In my view, the issue with self-nomination is that there are many community members out there who are diligent and kind and have good instincts for moderation -- but think that moderation isn't something they are qualified for. Let me tell you this: You don't have to be high-rep to be a good mod. You don't have to be an expert in English. You don't have to devote your entire day (or life) to moderation. Here's what you should look for in a moderator:

- patience
- an ability to de-escalate a heated situation
- equanimity
- an ability to see through different styles of communication to recognize what the core of the issue is -- that means letting people "berate" you or "snark at" you or use crappy punctuation and poor grammar.

That said, if we change the system to find other ways of nominating moderators, then the ones who are in it for the power trip or to win the game of internet points will just adjust their behavior to game the new system. That's a systemic problem and not one we're going to solve by clever coding.

For your next question, the results aren't streamed live but they are posted as immediately as it takes for the algorithm to run. Often, community members who frequent chat will wait in the [election chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43655/2016-english-language-moderator-election) for the results.

And for your last question ('is it clear yet?'), no, I don't think so, but I am interested to see how others will respond to it.

Comment: I upvoted this answer because it seems strong on factuality, sincerity, and (to use your word) equanimity. I do have a procedural question: How did deadrat's question get taken off hold? Did you clear it on your own, or did the moderators agree more broadly to lift the hold, or did it happen by some other means?

Comment: @SvenYargs According to the post history, JEL and Kit both voted to re-open. Presumably Kit'e vote, as a mod, was decisive.

Comment: @Sven As Dan indicated, there was one re-open vote, then I re-opened it myself. I felt I had something useful to say in response. I talked it over with Matt and he had no objection.

Comment: 1. *I felt I had something useful to say* And so you did. Thank you for that.

Comment: 2. Your first paragraph indicates that it's clear to you what issue I raised, but your last paragraph indicates the opposite. This leaves me bemused.

Comment: 3. *I'm sure you will forgive me if I take umbrage* I realize that this is partially formulaic, but there's nothing to forgive. Your umbrage is yours to take as you see fit. I'll just point out that I didn't say that anyone who would self-nominate is unqualified, just that self-nomination is evidence for disqualification. Not all evidence is dispositive. In my view, this makes the process suspect and not necessarily every moderator.

Comment: @deadrat I suppose it's more accurate to say I'm not clear on whether it is clear yet.

Comment: 4. My own preference is for moderators to have some, er, moderate expertise English, but your list is a good one. My point is that these are exactly the qualities that people are least likely to judge properly about themselves. Take the now-cancelled hold. Was that an example of equanimity and the ability to see through different styles of communication?

Comment: @deadrat You tell me. Do you feel it was? It was my intent to listen to and address your concerns from my perspective, but you're the only one who can tell me if I succeeded at that.

Comment: I was talking about the initial hold, not your cancellation thereof. Was the vote to hold an example of that equanimity and that ability to see through different styles of communication, which you hold so highly as characteristics of moderators? Or was it the reflexive urge to censor criticism on the feigned excuse that what was written was unclear?

Comment: @deadrat I don't believe it was either of those things. I think it was an example of how to appropriately handle an unclear question.

Comment: I propose a trade. I won't claim to be surprised that people who obtain a position by some process are offended when I criticize that process. In return, you won't deny that closing my post was a test that a moderator and a moderator wannabe failed miserably *by your own criteria* of patience, de-escalation, equanimity, and forbearance. As to the clarity of my post, I'll have to recuse myself, but I refer you to JEL's answer below.

Comment: I wouldn't accept that trade because closing your post was not a test (except perhaps in your mind) and it makes no difference to me if you are surprised by the consequences of your actions.

Comment: Let me make this easy: whatever mysteries my post contained, one thing was clear — I criticized the nominating process for moderators and by inevitable implication, at least some of the moderators themselves.  **Those who have or want authority to suppress expression must not use that authority to suppress criticism directed at themselves.** This isn’t a test in my mind. It’s the definition of abuse of power and conflict of interest. [con't]->

Comment: <-[cont't] You, yourself laid it out when you lectured me on the qualities of the good moderator: moderators have to take criticism even if that means letting people “berate” them, something my post hardly approached The irony is not lost on me that they very thing I pointed out — that those who seek authority tend to abuse it — came to pass. If it’s lost on you, I suggest you look harder.

Comment: I disagree that the exercise of power is by definition an abuse of power. I find your arguments amusing considering the preponderance of evidence to the contrary. Have you read Meta? There's plenty of criticism directed at the moderators here. Your question wasn't closed because it was a criticism of moderation but rather because it was a peeve without a clear purpose, just as if you had written "I don't like the color scheme. What are you going to do about it?" I know it is gratifying to your ego to feel persecuted, but this is all just routine work.

Comment: How is putting a post on hold so that it can be edited "suppressing criticism"? The post is still there for everyone to read. The post can be edited. That seems like the total opposite of suppression.

Comment: 1. Nowhere do I say that the exercise of power is by definition an abuse of power. Please have the courtesy to paraphrase me correctly. I said that an exercise of power that removes criticism of those in power is an abuse.

Comment: 2. *I find your arguments amusing* Thanks for the condescension. It's so refreshing. No, not refreshing. What's that other thing? Oh, yeah. Business as usual.

Comment: 3. *without a clear purpose* Yet clear enough for you to have reopened it and provided a cogent response. Go figure.

Comment: 4. *gratifying to your ego* With all due respect, you can stop reading my mind at any time, even if it's just routine work for you. Nobody here has the power to persecute me.

Comment: @deadrat I was only returning the condescension you had kindly lent me earlier. If you don't have a solution, why have the discussion? If you don't feel you will affect change, then why are you still here?

Comment: 1. *condescension* You have a bad habit of reading tone into text.

Comment: 2. *If you don't have a solution, why have the discussion?* NVZ asked me the same thing. Why must I have a solution? Might not someone cleverer than me or with experience different from me have a solution that hadn't occurred to me? Isn't that one purpose of discussion?

Comment: 3. *If you don't feel you will affect change, then why are you still here?* I believe you mean effect change. It's meta, but it's *ELU* meta.[insert emoticon of your choice here] But good question. I'm here (and at ELU proper) for my own purposes, which include both entertainment and edification. I realize that this puts a gulf between me and those who are here because they feel a proprietary interest in the site. I also realize that a better person would be more careful in what he shouts across the chasm. But that doesn't mean I'm not serious about what I post.

Comment: I'm afraid that I'm becoming that-internet-guy-who-has-to-have-the-last-word-on-everything. And I hate that guy. I'll be happy to respond to more questions. Indeed history shows that I love the sound of my own voice too much not to. But let me try for a tentative conclusion by repeating that I appreciate your re-opening the question (even if it was for your purposes and not mine), and I appreciate that you responded with a thoughtful answer.

Answer (score 13):

> Well, first of all, there's the rampant Dunning Kruger syndrome,

Moderators aren't claiming exclusive domain over all the knowledge posted to this site, so your understanding of Dunning-Kruger seems rampantly misapplied.

The truth is that *everyone* on this site shares in the (small 'm') moderator responsibilities, so the tools to curate this content become increasing available based on your success in posting and managing that content. A few users volunteer their time for a few administrative duties that require a degree of "trust" to carry them out.

> … those striving to attain authority over others thereby offer *prima facie* evidence that they shouldn't be allowed anywhere near that authority.

That's why it's an *election* and not a political *coup.*

You mention that there are other ways of selecting moderators, but don't actually mention them in this post; fair enough. But saying folks who choose to become police or join the military or the political apparat need not apply… that leaves birth right and compulsory enlistment through conscription. Since neither of those solutions seem likely, decrying that you don't like an election of appointees or volunteers does not seem terribly useful… or prescriptive.

Comment: 1. DK syndrome (*syndrome* is my contribution; *effect* is the actual term) has nothing to do with claims of exclusivity of knowledge, but with the misperception of one's expertise. The domain of that expertise under consideration here is moderation. Not "all the knowledge posted to this site", something I claim nowhere. I submit that the misapplication is not mine.

Comment: 2. My problem is with self-nomination. That's why I mention self-nomination in my post, not self-election.

Comment: 3. "[you] don't actually mention them" Actually, I mention one, in the next to last paragraph. It's neither birthright nor conscription, which aren't the only options left, as you yourself mention in your next sentence, namely appointment.

Comment: 4. If you'll forgive a blatant lie, I'm sorry you don't find my post useful. You're right; it's certainly not prescriptive. I don't have an answer. That could be what discussion might find, although that looks "rampantly" unlikely.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I may not have anything to say that is useful or detailed enough to warrant a response-answer, but I did suggest re-opening the topic, so I feel quixotically obliged.

To respond to your last question first, because it's low-hanging fruit, your topic-question never seemed unclear to me. You included a topic paragraph and a topic question, by gum, so why should it be considered unclear? It's true the question was a bit overblown, but that blowsiness (the rhetorical "possibly") was amusing though cliched, and would have been easily overlooked even if I didn't find the humor sympathetic.

The clarity of the topic was further crystalized by the details you provided, details that outlined precisely what you suppose could and does go wrong with self-nomination systems. I hope you won't object if I summarize my understanding of your suppositions, although I will inevitably misrepresent (to those who only read the words and clauses they can understand without effort) your position.

1. Those who nominate themselves for the duties of moderator at ELU may or may not be up to the task, but will invariably be confident that they are.
2. Those who nominate etc., by so doing, offer superficial (*prima facie*) evidence they're unfit for the duties for reasons other than or in addition to their confidence etc., as mentioned in 1.

Before going on, I have to submit that neither of those points are limiting. The first succeeds when there is a happy correspondence between confidence and ability (however much that correspondence may be purely fortuitous); the second succeeds when the superficial evidence fails to reflect the factual case.

I should hasten to add (as long as we're hastening to add things), that you didn't in my interpretation rule out that self-nomination could succeed when it came to selecting moderators. You simply seemed to find it unlikely or at least chancy that good moderators would rise to the top using a self-nomination process, and suggested there might be a better way, unknown to you.

It's this last that inspires my response. I'm by no means an expert on political matters, having assiduously avoided them for most of my life, perhaps due to a primal awareness of my inaptitude and innate inability. However, I do have some crude opinions based on what little I know, and will risk my footing in the quagmire of sewage I must navigate to express those opinions.

The political landscape has been somewhat remodeled in the last 35 years or so by the advent of refined communications mechanisms (for example, the web). My knowledge, and so my opinions, have been hard-pressed to integrate the changes so wrought.

However, I've heard it suggested, and tend to agree, that the most viable known alternative to democratic systems, benevolent dictatorship, is indeed superior—but is neither sustainable nor predeterminable...that is, a benevolent dictatorship cannot be systematically installed, nor can it be systematically sustained once installed.

It may well be that the changes wrought by the refinement of communication mechanisms in recent years lend themselves to an effective hybridization of democratic and benevolent dictatorship systems. It might even be that the Stackexchange microcosm is such a hybrid.

Having wandered so far afield, and offered my tentative, ignorant suggestions, it has become obvious what a legitimate 'closure' of your 'question' would look like. You mentioned it yourself: the 'question' might be better suited to StackExchange meta (supposing it has not already been discussed there), or perhaps, acknowledging that the time is ripe now for the discussion *here*, on one or more of the meta politics or philosophy StackExchange sites.

Comment: Let's also not forget that EL&U and SE as a whole have governance, but they are by no means a government. Participation in the community is voluntary. We have had users leave because they disagreed with policies or moderator selection, amongst other things. It is hardly on the level of international politics; closer to electing school board members.

Comment: @KitZ.Fox, oh sure ("closer to electing school board members"), not only with an eye to the pettiness, but also with an eye to the trivial squabbling occasioned. I should probably point out that I consider participation in any system of governance (a 'government')  "voluntary" in the sense you're using.

Comment: Well, it seemed pretty clear to me, but then I might be suffering from DKS when it comes the pellucidity of my own writing. To be fair, *prima facie* evidence is more than superficial evidence. It's that evidence which supports an argument at "first look", but which is rebuttable.

Comment: Cleanliness is next to godliness, and **blowsiness** is next to slovenliness. Is that the word you wanted?

Comment: @deadrat, cliched was close enough to coarse to suit me this once. Admittedly, it was self-indulgent wordplay, echoing "blow" in somewhat disparate terms, but it seemed likely I had only myself to indulge with this 'answer'. As for the *prima facie*...you're not a lawyer? The surface is what you see on first look, although I'd probably humor a lawyer who drew a distinction; for my part, no offense, but I thought your meaning was closer to 'superficial' than to the more technical legal sense. I'm usually willing to admit I'm wrong, though, and I'll toast your zythum regarding what you meant.

Comment: No, I'm not a lawyer, although I play one on misc.legal. Prima facie evidence is strong enough to make a case absent rebuttal.  So I was inviting a response. I just didn't think I'd get one that proved my point. I appreciate your response, although I'm going to refrain from voting here. You allow me describe my post as *Clear and blowsy towards morning with intermittent periods of sarcasm*. So that's a good thing. And I'm happy to toast your zythum right back at you (if you know what I mean).